# Validation of variation to Gitflow workflow

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm looking at getting validation on a variation to the Gitflow workflow.

Example:

Developer starts a new feature branch based on a JIRA ticket. Developer 2 starts another feature branch based on a separate JIRA ticket.

These 2 features once completed development, need to be tested before being deployed live.

Each developer merges their feature into `env/test` branch. The reason that we have created a `env/test` branch, is that these features can be tested internally and approved, but only one of those features may be approved by the client to be pushed into production.

When the client has approved a feature, the develop can then merge the releaseable features into the `develop` branch (develop being 100% ready for release). We could subsequently add a release branch as well.

This maintains the core gitflow functionality, but the `develop` branch is not used as a complete integration testing branch, this instead moves to the `env/test` branch.

I can't think of another way to do this?

Comment: You could also use the feature branches for testing/approval.  For example, you merge `develop` into `feature-x` (if `develop` has moved forward since `feature-x` was branched), then give `feature-x` to the customer for approval, and merge it into `develop` afterwards (if accepted).  There's no need for yet another integration branch.

Comment: we thought of that, but the way our environments are setup, and our testing works, we can't have a separate environment for each feature, as we have 5+ features on the go at any one time